# Java Thread ,Freeze my UI

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to check the value of 2 strings every minute, and close the Thread 
when the value will be different , but this code freeze my UI. that's the code.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    //Download sourcecode on String
    String secondaChar = result;
    //Strings declaration
    String First = "";
    String Second = "";
    try 
    {   
        //Writing sourcecode on string
        Write(secondaChar);
        String ReadingFile="FileSorgente";
        First=reading(ReadingFile);
        while (true) 
        {   
            // Downloading new sourcecode on string
            secondaChar = result.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
            //writing new SC on string
            Scrittura(secondaChar);
            // new SC on second string
            Second = Reading(ReadingFile);
            // check until 2 strings are the same
            if(First.equalsIgnoreCase(Second))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Keep Checking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {         
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALSE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                break;
            } 
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    textView.setText("Usless");
}
```

Reading and Writing are 2 different method, i've test this in java befor and it worked, but probably in Android sdk i have to do something different.

Comment: `onPostExecute()` runs on the main thread. I'm pretty sure you wanted to do that in the `doInBackground()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute long running tasks - for instance, `Thread.sleep(...)` - in the `doInBackground()` - which is running off the UI thread.

`onPostExecute()` is supposed to be only called after the `doInBackground()` completes, and is used exactly to update the UI - thus it runs on the UI thread. Every delay you make there will cause your app to become unresponsive.

To fix this, move your logic to `doInBackground()`. Remeber that all the UI operations, though, have to happen on the UI thread. So, for instance, showing toasts would have to be done from `onPostExecute()` or from `onProgressUpdate()`.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/782609) for an example on how to do this. Note that `Thread.sleep()` is called there as well, but in `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
                protected void doInBackground(params....) 
                {
                    //Download sourcecode on String
                    String secondaChar = result;
                    //Strings declaration
                    String First = "";
                    String Second = "";
                    try 
                    {   
                        //Writing sourcecode on string
                        Write(secondaChar);
                        String ReadingFile="FileSorgente";
                        First=reading(ReadingFile);
                        while (true) 
                        {   
                            // Downloading new sourcecode on string
                            secondaChar = result.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
                            //writing new SC on string
                            Scrittura(secondaChar);
                            // new SC on second string
                            Second = Reading(ReadingFile);
                            // check until 2 strings are the same
                            if(First.equalsIgnoreCase(Second))
                            {
                                  publishProgress( "Keep Checking" );
                            }
                            else
                            {         
                                  publishProgress( "FALSE" ); 
                                break;
                            } 
                            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                     publishProgress("Usless");
                }

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         showToast(progress[0]);
}
```

Comment: Then , added onProgressUpdate and publishProgress. Have updated dummy codes.